# How to get largest number in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a code `VARCHAR` field that I want to auto-increment if the user doesn't provide a code of their own. For example:

```
`code`
- '5'
- '8'
- 's987'
- '981A'
```

In this case, the largest (pure) number would be 8, so I want to autoincrement to 9. How would I do this? So, I want to:

(1) Get the largest number (even though it's stored as a `VARCHAR`) that is currently in my table. In the above entries, `8` would be the largest number, since `s987` and `981A` are not valid numbers.
(2) Add one to this number to get the new autoincrement number.

Comment: not clear enough, can you clarify?

Comment: MAX(code) ...WHERE code REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT max(CAST(code AS UNSIGNED))+1 FROM myTable WHERE code REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it-

```
SELECT MAX(code)+1 FROM table_name WHERE code REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$' AND code*1>0;
```